# Left 4 Dead 2 dedicated server Steam authentication problems

Tags: debian-wheezy, libraries, gameserver

I'm running a game dedicated server for the Valve game Left 4 Dead 2 on my housed root server. I had one running for years back when I was still running Debian Squeeze (6, oldstable, x86_64) on my servers and wanted to set one up again now on Debian Wheezy (7, stable, multiarch x86/x86_64). When running the server I see some error messages and noone seems to be able to connect to the server.

I start the dedicated server with the following command:

```
sudo -u l4d2 /opt/left4dead2/srcds_run -steam_dir /opt/left4dead2/steamcmd -steamcmd_script /opt/left4dead2/left4dead2.steamcmd -autoupdate -ip 1.2.3.4 -port 27016
```

When starting the dedicated server process I see the following lines in the output:

```
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; SteamAPI_IsSteamRunning() failed.
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; unable to locate a running instance of Steam, or a local steamclient.dll.
```

And after some probably unrelated cable-noise-like blobs of text:

```
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; SteamAPI_IsSteamRunning() failed.
dlopen failed trying to load:
/opt/left4dead2/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so with error:
/opt/left4dead2/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The server is configured as a Steam Group server (I have some echo commands in the config file and know that it has been successfully loaded) and should be visible to anyone in the referenced group who is ingame. It doesn't show up, nor can I join manually by issuing the ingame command `connect 1.2.3.4:27016`. The respective UDP port is open on the system firewall.

Some months ago Valve replaced their `hldsupdatetool` utility for downloading the game server files with a new tool called [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD), this tool, according to a Valve mailing list announcement, is now mandatory.

I used the following command to install the game server:

```
cd /opt/left4dead2
sudo -u l4d2 steamcmd/steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir .. +app_update 222860 validate +quit
```

I managed to get rid of the last three lines by creating the directories `/opt/left4dead2/.steam/sdk32` and copying the `steamclient.so` from `/opt/left4dead2/steamcmd/linux32/` to that location, which was described as a solution to the problem [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Unable_to_locate_a_running_instance_of_Steam). But I still cannot connect to the server at all.

I hope someone can help me with this and that Server Fault is the right place for such a problem. I didn't see any better matching Stack Exchange branch to post it on.

Comment: I really dislike being downvoted without hearing a reason. Please be so nice and explain what's wrong here, maybe I can fix it.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but we do not generally consider running Game servers to be within the scope of serverfault, which is primarily aimed and support systems in a professional capacity.  I am not sure this would really fit on any stackexchange site.  You might want to see if there are any vendor support forums.

Comment: I am a professional server administrator trying to host game servers. Why was this no problem here: https://serverfault.com/questions/88355/isa-2000-and-cod-mw2-steam and why is there even a tag for gameserver questions then? And even more important: Is there a better suited Stack Exchange branch for this to be moved to?

Comment: @aef That's from 3 years ago... not sure it's applicable anymore, and even if it is, the community's disposition and standards have changed. We get a lot of useless "help me with my home server" questions, and are sick of it, so may be a little fast to VTC and downvote anything that looks like such a question nowadays.  Not sure your question is especially topical, or even that anyone here has the ability to provide a useful answer, but I threw a reopen vote on it.  (And no, I don't think there's a "better" SE site for your question.  You might just be in too small a niche.)

Comment: Does `/opt/left4dead2/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so` exist and if not, does `steamclient.so` exist anywhere on your system?

Comment: Don't take the downvoting personally. I've noticed that the old guard on this site tend to downvote certain things, regardless of the actual value of the question.  Woe unto the unwary who mention they're a developer...

Comment: @Ladadadada yes, it exists after I copied it there as described.

Answer (score 1):

**Googling the error gives the following:**

You may get the following error when starting a Server with Linux

> [S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; unable to locate a running
>   instance of Steam, or a local steamclient.dll.

Resolve the issue by copying steamclient.so to the ~/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so directory

> cp steamcmd/linux32/steamclient.so ~/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Running_SteamCMD

Comment: I did so, and wrote so in my question. But this didn't resolve the whole problem and especially not the error you referred to.

Comment: @aef Does your service account have permissions over the new files steam cmd installed?

Comment: @aef Also, if you have resolved these errors, you should note that more clearly in your question.  After re-reading your question I'm left puzzled as to the state things are actually in.  From your last statement, "I still cannot connect", implies that the server has started, is running, but players cannot join it.  If that is accurate I would adjust the question to clarify this.

Comment: I made sure the l4d2 account has at least read access to all files in /opt/left4dead2 and subfolders.